# Sidekiq web returns a blank page with empty body

Tags: sidekiq, ruby-on-rails-6, sidekiq-monitor

I am trying to access the sidekiq web however I am getting a blank page. No error or message.

I am using the following env.:

```
ruby 2.6.3
Rails 6.0.2.1 (inc. zeitwerk)
rack 2.1.2
sidekiq 6.0.4
```

If I am grading sidekiq down to version 5.2.7 without zeitwerk, I get no content from the sidekiq web as well. So this must be a generall issue.

If I access the sidekiq web a blank page / html body is returned. Thin show the following requests:

```
Started GET "/admin/sidekiq" for ::1 at 2020-02-07 11:32:58 +0100
Started GET "/admin/sidekiq/stylesheets/bootstrap.css" for ::1 at 2020-02-07 11:32:58 +0100
Started GET "/admin/sidekiq/stylesheets/application.css" for ::1 at 2020-02-07 11:32:58 +0100
Started GET "/admin/sidekiq/stylesheets/application-dark.css" for ::1 at 2020-02-07 11:32:58 +0100
```

**Any idea is appreciated**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

rack version 2.1.2 is [buggy](https://github.com//rack/rack/issues/1504). I have been downgrading to version 2.0.8.

GemFile

`gem 'rack', "2.0.8"`

Comment: I also had this problem with rack 2.2.2. Downgrading to 2.0.8 fix it

Comment: this issue about incorrect content-length might be the source:
https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/4440
https://github.com/rack/rack/issues/1504

Answer (score 3):

**Update**

Fixed on `new_relic_rpm >= 6.9.0`

There was an issue with Rack versions above `2.0.8` where using agent-based Browser instrumentation injection causing Content-Length headers to not match the content size, which in turns causes content truncation in some cases.

https://github.com/newrelic/newrelic-ruby-agent/pull/312

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28861098)

Comment: @Rob Thanks for the feedback. I have updated the answer to follow that criteria. Let me know if you find it insufficient.